# Change Appearance of Modal UIActivityViewController

Tags: objective-c, ios, modalviewcontroller, uiappearance, uiactivityviewcontroller

How do I change the appearance of the navigation bar of a `UIActivityViewController` mail compose object used in a modal sharing action?

[image: UINavigationBar - Wrong Tint]

`UIActivityViewController` conforms to `UIAppearance`, so I thought the following does work but it doesn't. The navigation bar stays default blue.

```
activityVC.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor greyColor];
```

Context:

```
    - (IBAction)share {
        NSString *textToShare = ...;
        NSURL *url = ...;

        NSArray *activityItems = [[NSArray alloc]  initWithObjects:textToShare,url,nil];

        UIActivity *activity = [[UIActivity alloc] init];
        NSArray *applicationActivities = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:activity, nil];
        UIActivityViewController *activityVC =
        [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:activityItems applicationActivities:applicationActivities];
        [activityVC setExcludedActivityTypes:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:                                              UIActivityTypeMessage,UIActivityTypeCopyToPasteboard,
UIActivityTypeAssignToContact,UIActivityTypePostToWeibo,                                              UIActivityTypePrint,UIActivityTypeSaveToCameraRoll,
                                              nil]];

        activityVC.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor greyColor];

        [self presentViewController:activityVC animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
```

How can I change the tint of the `UINavigationBar` from blue to grey.

Comment: did you try to force the navigation bar to be re-render using the setNeedDisplay method maybe?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do this in your Application Delegate it will change the color of navigation bar throughout the application where ever navigation bar is shown

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:.9 green:.9 blue:.9 alpha:1]];
```

you can also change the text color and font using this in your Application Delegate

```
NSDictionary *navbarTitleTextAttributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                           [UIColor redColor],UITextAttributeTextColor,
                                           [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:19],UITextAttributeFont,
                                           nil];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:navbarTitleTextAttributes];
```

Comment: I'm presenting a navigation controller modally and it is defaulting to black, even though I have the [UINavigationBar appearance] set in AppDelegate

Comment: iOS 7 has another method @property(nonatomic,retain) UIColor *barTintColor NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(7_0) UI_APPEARANCE_SELECTOR;  // default is nil